# DataTables row content dependent on JSON data

Tags: jquery, datatables

My web page receives json data comprising of an array, an array of objects and a string. Eg:

```
data = { labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',] , 
staff: [ {'name' : 'aaa', 'dept': 'bbb', 'region': 'ccc', 'mgr': 'ddd', 'active': 1, 'id': '111'}, { }, { }, { }, { } ], err: 'error msg'}
```

I can draw a table displaying each object property as cell for a row corresponding to the object in array of objects staff.

However, depending on the value of data.staff[key].active , I want the row to be of certain colour and last cell to have a button or a received value. 
Lastly, is I also possible to draw the table where each  element in table body has a custom attribute whose value is also obtained from a key property of the returning json array of objects

Comment: Yes you can do all that in (rowCallback)[https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback].  If you post some more code (ie the datatables initiasation code), we can probably help you more.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [rowCallBack](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback).

```
rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
    if(data.staff[key] == active){
       $(row).addClass('highlight');
    }
}
```